# How to echo a status message after each code statement is executed in real time?

Tags: php

We've all seen those programs the show a message after each task is done and if there's an error at some point, it shows that error. For example:

```
Task A Done
Task B Fone
etc...
// If an error happens
Error Completing Task Q: {error message}
// Or if no error
Task X Done
Task Z Done
Complete
```

I want to do this with a script I have to show me exactly where the script has an issue. Now I don't have any pre-defined error messages set up, just confirmations. But they can be made later if need be. I don't need anyone to give me a new code for how to zip archives because this script works fine. I'm going to be editing it for a new function and I want to be able to see the processes, especially if I'm using it on the front-end as a service for my users.

The code:

```
$zip=new ZipArchive();
if (file_exists($archive)) {
    unlink($archive);
}
if (extension_loaded('zip')) { 
    $debug='<b>Extension (.zip) Is Loaded</b><br /><b><u>Beginning Search For:</u></b> (' . $folder . ')<br />';
    if (file_exists(realpath($folder))) {
        $debug='<b><u>Found:</u></b> (' . $folder . ')<br />';
        if ($zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE | ZipArchive::CREATE )) {
            $debug='<b><u>Archive Opened:</u></b> (' . $archive . ')<br />';
            if (is_dir(realpath($folder))) {
                $debug='<b>Beginning Recursive Directory Scan Of Folder: (</b>' . basename($folder) . ')<br />';
                $files=new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    if (is_dir(realpath($file))) {
                        $debug='<b><u>Adding Directory:</u></b> (' . basename($file) . ')<br />';
                        $zip->addEmptyDir(zipDir($file));
                        $dirTree='<b>|</b><br /><b>|----</b>' . $file . '<br />';
                    } elseif (is_file($file)) {
                        $debug='<b><u>Adding File:</u></b> (' . basename($file) . ')<br />';
                        $zip->addFromString(insertFile($file), file_get_contents($file));
                        $dirTree='<b>|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|----</b>' . basename($file) . '<br />';
                    } else {
                        exit($zip->getStatusString());
                    }
                }
            } else if (is_file($folder)) {
                $debug='<b><u>Adding File In Archive Root:</u></b> (' . basename($folder) . ')<br />';
                $zip->addFromString(zipDir($folder), file_get_contents($folder));
            } else {
                $debug='<b>No Directories Or Files Found In (' . $folder . ')</b>';
            }
        } if ($zip->close() !== FALSE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I have the `$debug` statements as well as the `$$dirTree` statements. I wanted to have/give the option to display a stack status messages or a directory tree(also in real time). So how would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I tried the `ob_flush(); flush();` in a function so it could be called universally:

```
function debugScript($string, $x='0') {
    if ($x === 1) {
        echo $string;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}
```

And edited all the `$debug` statements like so:

```
$debug='{message}<br />'; debugScript($debug, 1);
```

It shows the messages just fine but only after the script finishes, not in real time. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: Push it into the array $array[ ] = $debug

Comment: Ok and will that make it show the $debug statements as they occur in the script?

Comment: You can append the message to the html like this:-<script type="text/javascript">
<?php foreach ($viewData['cure'] as $cure): ?>
$("#new").append('<label for="nice_text<?php echo $cure["id"] ?>">ID Type</label><input type="text" id="nice_text<?php echo $cure["id"] ?>"/>" name="cureIdtype" class="input-text" value="<?php echo (string)$cure["id_type"] ?>"/>');
<?php endforeach; ?>
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the PHP after you echo message?

```
ob_flush();flush();
```

This will force PHP to send output to client (i.e. any echo you executed since the last flush)

[Check out PHP manual to see code examples.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Comment: Just tried that, it went straight to "This page is not working" in browser.

Comment: @the_software_trader_official Works for me, I tested your script. I added echo/flush after every loop (with 1 sec timeout, just as a test -`sleep(1);` ) and it went through every loop. You probably made syntax error, check your code again.

Comment: Updated question to show what I did after some edits to get rid of the browser error.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to use ob_start, which starts the output buffering. I think if you want immediately send output to the browser, then buffering should be disabled altogether. The flush function can be used to force Php output to be sent to the browser.

If the flush function alone does not work, then you need to disable output buffering in your php.ini. The output from php may also be buffered at several locations such as php extensions, web browser, web browser module and proxy server. The following directive should be added to php.ini for disabling output buffering:

```
zlib.output_compression = 0;
output_buffering = 0;
```